# mysql error You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, database

When I tried the following command to try to grant privileges, I am getting the following error, can anyone tell me why there is a syntax error?

```
mysql> grant all privileges on ufo.* to 'abc'@'%' identified by 'abc';




ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'abc'' at line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try avoid identified  by  ...

```
grant all privileges on ufo.* to 'abc'@'%';
```